# C++ Linked List Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, linked-list

Alright, I'm trying to write a program in C++ that deals with a double-linked list. Specifically, the list contains a collection of artwork objects as its nodes. In this particular function, I'm trying to remove nodes through the "sell" command, but I'm getting this error on several lines:

Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I've done my research and I've found that this type of error commonly arises when you try to assign values when you actually want to compare them, or if you're trying to assign values to a constant. However, I don't think that's my problem. Here's the problem code:

```
// Sell At Function: This function sells the specified artwork.
void CR_ArtCollection::sell_at(string title, ostream& log)
{
    CR_ArtWorks* walker = first;

    while(walker != NULL)
    {
        if(title == walker->get_title())
        {
            walker->get_next()->get_prev() = walker->get_prev(); // Error
            walker->get_prev()->get_next() = walker->get_next(); // Error
            delete walker;
            walker = NULL;
        }
        else walker = walker->get_next();
    }
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be incredibly appreciative.

Comment: Could you at least say which line the compiler is complaining about?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite obvious - `get_prev` and `get_next` return **r-values**. That means you can't assign to them.

Check your interface for a method similar to `set_next` and `set_prev` and call it as:

```
walker->get_next()->set_prev(walker->get_prev());
walker->get_prev()->set_next(walker->get_next());
```

As the names suggest - `get_xxxx`, those methods are there so you can **get** the values, not also set them.

Comment: @CliftonRoberts so you actually had the `set_prev` and `set_next` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if a function returns a primitive type such as a integer or a pointer it is not legal to assign to the result of the function. That's the error you have.

One possibility would be to change your get_prev and get_next function to return references to pointers.

But I don't suggest you do that. Your code clearly needs redesigning. You should add an erase function to your linked list class. That way the pointer manipulation code will be in the  CR_ArtWorks class where it belongs, instead of the CR_ArtCollection class where it doesn't.